# WPF Adding a border to all images on MouseOver

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

New to WPF.

I am trying to wrap my head around the XAML syntax but it's only been a few days. I was wondering how I would apply a MouseOver effect, specifically a shadow, to all Image tags within this block of code:

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <WrapPanel.Style>
                <Style>
                </Style>
            </WrapPanel.Style>
            <Image Source="../Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="0,10,10,10"/>
            <Image Source="../Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
            <Image Source="../Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
            <Image Source="../Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="10,10,0,10"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You can override the Image template to apply animation  at `IsMouseOver` `ControlTemplate.Trigger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will apply DropShadowEffect :

```
         <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <WrapPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </WrapPanel.Resources>

                <WrapPanel.Style>
                    <Style>
                    </Style>
                </WrapPanel.Style>
                <Image Source="/Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="0,10,10,10"/>
                <Image Source="/Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                <Image Source="/Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                <Image Source="/Image.jpg" Width="200" Height="296" Margin="10,10,0,10"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```